# TkbmMemTable - how to add a field during runtime?

Tags: delphi

I have a simple csv file, which is opened like this:

```
  FkbmCSVStreamFormat.sfDef := FkbmCSVStreamFormat.sfDef - [sfLoadDef];
  FkbmMemTable.LoadFromFileViaFormat(AFilename, FkbmCSVStreamFormat);
```

How can I add a new Field during runtime to the MemTable?
Something like:

```
    DataSet.FieldDefs.Add('MyNewField', ftString, 20, False);
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Greetings
Klaus

Comment: What is the result of the Add you show? Which error do you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly like any other dataset:

For example: for a string field (Name:sFieldName, size:iSize, your kbmMemTable is myDataset):

myDataset.FieldDefs.Add(sFieldName, ftString, iSize);
myDataset.fielddefs[mydataset.fielddefs.count-1].CreateField(myDataset);